# ¿Cómo agregar datos a una lista usando el método POST en Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Tengo un pequeño script en Flask en el cual agrego datos a una lista desde un formulario HTML el problema es que a la hora de hacer lista.append(elementos) sólo agrega un elemento y si vuelvo a pasar el valor reinicia la lista.

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msj = request.form['mensaje']
        lista = ['Lista de elementos']
        lista.append(msj)
        return render_template('index.html', lista=lista)
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Supongamos que introduzco "hola" y después "cómo estás", entonces la lista aparece:

```
['Lista de elementos', 'hola']
['Lista de elementos', 'cómo estás']
```

En lugar de:

```
['Lista de elementos', 'hola', 'cómo estás']
```

¿Qué puede estár sucediendo?

Comment: Si has encontrado la solución a tu problema debes de ponerla en la sección de respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

**Actualzación:** Ya lo solucioné.

Lista de elementos debe ir fuera del `def`:

```py
lista = ['Lista de elementos']
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msj = request.form['mensaje']
        lista.append(msj)
        return render_template('index.html', lista=lista)
    return render_template("index.html")
```